# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.Attraction.Name')

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, sequelize.js

I have the following request in **Get**:

```
app.get('/attraction/:routeid', async(req,res)=>{
    let response = await attraction_routes.findAll({
        attributes: ['attractionId'],
        where:{routeid: req.params.routeid},
        raw: true,
        include: [{
            model: Attraction,
            required: true,
            attributes: ['Name','Desc','Address']
        }],
        order: [['id', 'ASC']]
    });
    res.json(response)
});
```

And it returns the following **JSON**:

```
[
   {
      "attractionId":1,
      "Attraction.Name":"Mirante Cerro Santa Lucia",
   },
   {
      "attractionId":2,
      "Attraction.Name":"Cajon del Maipo",
   }
]
```

I want to access the ***Attraction.Name*** attribute in the rendering of my item on my page, but when I define it in my variable there is an error **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.Attraction.Name')* *

```
function renderPost(item){
return(
  <View style={styles.card}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>
      {item.Attraction.Name}
    </Text>
  </View>
)
};
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcwui.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key itself has a dot, so you need to do:

```
<Text style={styles.title}>
  {item['Attraction.Name']}
</Text>
```

The way you currently have it would work for:

```
{
   "attractionId":2,
   "Attraction": {
     "Name":"Cajon del Maipo"
   }
}
```